# how to send $_POST by a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

hello i have problems sending an id in a form.

the structure of the site is:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
    ...create the session from some variables...
$_SESSION['a'] = $var;
$var = $_SESSION['a'];
}else{
$var = $_SESSION['a'];

    if (isset($_POST["one"]) ){
        echo "post one was send";
    }
    if (isset($_POST["two"]) ){
        echo "post en was send";
    }

echo "session already exists.";
}
```

the form where it will be send is placed at the end of the page and will be embedded into html by an excluded php:

```
echo '...
      <ul class="drop_down">
    <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">      
        <input type="submit" id="one" name="one" value="one"/><div>set one</div>
    </form>
    <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">  
        <input type="submit" id="two" name="two" value="two"><div>set two</div>
    </form>
      </ul>
     ...';
```

so the strange about that is, that the form not seems to be send because the first part of the code works as it should do just the else part does not work when sending the form. it just will be displayed the echo text below the conditions for post-method.

so if there is someone who could tell how i can solve this i really would apreciate.

thanks alot.

UPDATE:

okay, using the request-method without action makes echo out the message. i thought it will work.
now the problem is, that when i will send the post the session should have been changed. this is not the case and i have no clue why this is not working.

so the original code is like that:

```
if (isset($_POST["tr"]) ){
    $_SESSION['a'] = "tr";
    echo "post tr was send and session has changed to tr";
    }
```

Comment: if you don't have a value for `$_SESSION['a']`, you will never see the `echo`'s in the else statement

Comment: html element IDs are **NEVER** sent with a form submission. Only the `name` and `value` attributes will be.

Comment: If the form is posting back to the same URL as the page is served up on, you don't need to put an `action`.

Comment: Please post output of `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: there is no output for var_dump($_POST); how is that possible???

Answer (score 2):

If you have a forms like this

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" name="formA">
</form>

<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" name="formB">
</form>
```

Then you can check like this

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['formA']) ...
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['formB']) ...
```

Comment: with the `action=/a` Whill try to foward the variables to another page, where the OP wants it to be contained into 1 page

Comment: @user1902584, the `action` attributes were just there as examples. They've been removed as they're not really relevant.

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. this does not work.

Comment: now it works. had to wait for the server... thanks alot for your help.